# ¿Por qué el botón siempre está de color rojo?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un código muy básico donde a un botón con clases "btn active" le doy entre otros un color azul a la clase ".btn" y que cuando sea activado ya sea por clic u otros se ponga de color rojo, esto asignándole el color rojo a la clase ".btn.active".

El problema está en que he visto en varios videos y hasta preguntando a ChatGPT que en el navegador debe salir PRIMERO el botón de color azul y al pulsarlo cambie a rojo. Pues yo hago lo mismo pero a mi directamente me sale el botón de color rojo, como si .btn.active estuviera por encima de .btn y no tengo ni idea de por qué.

Ya intenté cambiar el orden de los estilos en CSS y recargué el caché de la página de mi navegador pero nada, siempre se muestra el botón ya de color ROJO.

```css
.btn {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
.btn.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Botón con cambio de color</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codigo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn active">Haz clic aquí</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Adjunto lo que me sale en navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

El botón siempre es de color rojo porque siempre tiene las clases `btn` y `active`.

Es probable que te hayas confundido con la pseudo-clase [active](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:active) que se denota como `:active`.

Además de que la clase `active` a secas ya no cumple ninguna función.

El código queda así:

```css
.btn {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
.btn:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Botón con cambio de color</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codigo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn">Haz clic aquí</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu botón tiene la clase `btn active`, en donde primero tu botón tendrá los estilos de `btn` y luego el de `active`, es por eso que el último estilo que obtiene tu botón es el color rojo porque el `active` (que es la última clase) le indicas que el color sea rojo.

Quiere decir que si tenemos un botón sin la clase `active`, no ocurrirá el estilo de `active`, que es el color rojo. Ejemplo:

```css
.btn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Haz clic aquí</button>
<button class="btn active">Haz clic aquí</button>
```